# Not able to get the Rules from outlook 2010 Session.DefaultStore object

Tags: c#, outlook

I am using the following code to get outlook 2010 rules. But it throws exception that is:

```
"This store does not support rules. Could not complete the operation."
```

I am using console application to get outlook rules.

```
public void removeRules(MSOutlook.Application app)
{
  Console.WriteLine(" in removeRules ");
  string ruleName = "SvcForeRule";
  try
  {
    // Get Rules from Session.DefaultStore object 
    foreach (MSOutlook.Rules rules in app.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules())
    {
      Console.WriteLine(" rules count : " + rules.Count);
      for (int i = 1; i <= rules.Count; i++)
      {
        MSOutlook.Rule rule1 = rules[i];
        if (rule1.Name == ruleName)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(" rules Name  : " + rule1.Name);
          rules.Remove(i);
          Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rule1);
          break;
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rule1);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception in remove rules : " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What line of code generates the exception? Did you try to debug the code?

First of all, make sure that you have all the latest updates and service packs for Outlook 2010 installed.

Then try to change the following line code:

```
app.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules
```

To

```
app.Session.Stores(1).GetRules
```

The [This store does not support rule - MS Outlook 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6b106b6f-7723-4125-92c1-5e94c64b9315/this-store-does-not-support-rule-ms-outlook-2010) forum thread describes exactly the same issue.

Comment: foreach (MSOutlook.Rules rules in app.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules())
this line throws exception. 
but now its working,
thanks Eugene.